# Showing JSON object in EJS when clicked on div

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a set of json data stored in js array.

```
let data = [{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
{
"name":"Jack",
"age":35,
"cars":[ "Ferrari", "Mercedes", "Volkswagen" ]
}];
```

And I have a Partial in EJS:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 fh5co-item-wrap">
<a href='data' rel="modal:open" class="fh5co-listing-item">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="fh5co-listing-copy">
        <h2><%= data[i].name%></h2>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
<% } %>
```

This shows All of my List which is OK, but I want to when I click on a Particular Item to show JSON data just for that Object.
This is my modal partial:

```
<div id="data" class="data" >
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>  
<p><%= data.[i].name%></p>
<p><%= data.[i].age%></p>
<% } %>
</div>
```

And this is my index.js expressjs route:

```
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
res.render('pages/data' ,{ data: data})
})
```

Now it shows my Partial but Listing every Object.
So to clarify: I want to when a list item is clicked to show in modal only data from that object.

Hope I was clear enough. Ask whatever is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change route as

```
app.get('/data/:name', function (req, res) {
   const mydata = data.filter((d) => {
        return d.name === req.params.name;
    })[0];
   res.render('pages/data' ,{ data: mydata})
})
```

Change your modal as

```
<div id="data" class="data">
   <p><%= data.name%></p>
   <p><%= data.age%></p>
</div>
```

Change your Link display EJS as

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 fh5co-item-wrap">
    <a href='data/<%=data[i].name%>' rel="modal:open" class="fh5co-listing-item">
      <img src="images/img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="fh5co-listing-copy">
        <h2><%= data[i].name %></h2>
        <pre class="json-data"><%= JSON.stringify(data[i]) %></pre>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I tried this in all of different ways and the best I could do is only showing the first object cause of [0] in route. How can I fetch all of Objects not just [0] ?

Comment: have you tried appending href path uri with name of data[i]. Ex. /data/John, /data/Jack

Comment: Yeah, nothing happens. I tried appending id and the best that happened is opening only first object or  whichever specified in [0]. look at this code and see if you can do anything. Thanks https://glitch.com/edit/#!/alabaster-magic

Comment: Fixed in this. just have a glance at this project https://glitch.com/edit/#!/smart-albacore and APP url for testing https://smart-albacore.glitch.me